# Parse - afterSave and accessing request object?

Tags: parse-platform

I send a request to parse that includes a `Comment` object that has a pointer to a `User` named "from".

In afterSave I need to read this and I'm having all kinds of problems. `beforeSave` works just fine, but I want to execute this code in `afterSave`;

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Comment", function(request) {
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");

    userQuery.get(request.object.get("from").id, {
        success: function(user) {

                },
                error : function(error) {
                    console.error("errrrrrrrr" + error);
                }
        });
});
```

Here is the log I'm seeing on parse

```
errrrrrrrrr [object Object]
```

EDIT:

I also tried

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query("_User");
```

Comment: If you then modify the user in the success block. Doesn't this amount to a total of 3 requests for a single action?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I had to call `useMasterKey`, since I was fetching a user data.
I'm not entirely sure about this though so I'll keep this question open.

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```

Try to fetch the pointer directly:

```
var fromUserPointer = request.object.get("from");

fromUserPointer.fetch().then(function(fetchedFromUser){



},function(error){


});
```

Comment: Tried that with the same result

Comment: Ok. I've edited the Answer with another possible solution. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I ended up doing. But I could not get it to work without useMasterKey

Comment: Unless you've put some restricted ACL in the User table you should be able to read a user row, also without using the masterkey. Basically no ACL is set in the User table (so, should be publicRead:true), and i'm able to query that table without any problem, it's strange

Comment: Hmmm, will give it another try without using masterKey

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach.

This assumes that you have the comment object available right there, or at least its id.

Instead of querying the User collection, how about this:

```
var commentQuery = new Parse.Query("Comment");
commentQuery.include("from");
commentQuery.get(<commentId>, {
    success: function (comment)
    {
        var user = comment.get("from"); // Here you have the user object linked to the comment :)
    },
    error: function (error)
    {
        console.log("ERROR: ");
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```